# Remove input placeholder using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

does anyone know how to remove input placeholder using jquery?

I want to do is if one of the `inputbox` got a value...all the inputbox placeholder will be remove....does anyone know how to do that?

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="1.)">
<input type="text" name="age" placeholder="2.)">
<input type="text" name="address" placeholder="3.)">
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Should work:

```
$(':input').removeAttr('placeholder');
```

Answer (score 4):

Get all the inputs, and attach a change event handler, inside the event handler get the value from all the inputs, join the values together, and if it's still nothing, none of the inputs have a value, if it has length, at least one of the inputs have value, and you can remove the placeholder attributes :

```
var inputs = $('input[type="text"]');

inputs.on('change', function() {
    if ( $.map(inputs, function(el) { return el.value; }).join('').length ) 
        inputs.removeAttr('placeholder');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bfDWT/1/)

Comment: He *might* want that explaining a little :p

Comment: @Archer - like that !

Answer (score 3):

## I DONT RECCOMEND to remove placeholder

instead, make a focus, and this will automatically hide placeholder at that moment:

```
$(element).focus();
```

Comment: This is the correct solution to me, because the placeholder will reappear when the text is removed from the input. You also can focus all your elements in sequence, so it does also work with multiple inputs. In the removeAttr solution the placeholder will stay removed until it is explicitly set as attire again.

Answer (score 2):

[.removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

```
var txtbox = $('input[type="text"]');
txtbox.change(function () {
    txtbox.removeAttr('placeholder');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="name"]').removeProp('placeholder');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the placeholder to an empty string on `keyup`.

```
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function() {
    $("input[type=text]").attr("placeholder","")
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FdcAW/)

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?  Untested, but it should remove the placeholder attribute on the first change to any input.

```
var inputs = $('input');

inputs.one('change', function(){
    inputs.removeAttr('placeholder');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gone one step further, in case you also want this.  This code will remove the placeholder text in all text inputs if any of them have a value, but if you then remove all the values it will put the placeholder text back.  May not be necessary, but have it...

```
var $inputs = $("input:text");

$inputs.on("change", function() {
    if ($.map($inputs, function(el) { if (el.value) return o.value; }).length) {
        $inputs.each(function() {
            this._placeholder = this.placeholder;
            $(this).removeAttr("placeholder");
        });
    } else {
        $inputs.each(function() {
            this.placeholder = this._placeholder;
        });
    }
});
```

**[jsfiddle example...](http://jsfiddle.net/Jz8L7/)**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reset it back to the original placeholder instead of removing it entirely try clearing the val() first then adding the attr()

$('#name').val('');

$('#name').attr('placeholder', 'whatever your previous placeholder was');

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
if ($(input).val()) {
$(input).attr("placeholder", "")
}
```

Comment: `$(input)` won't select any inputs, unless `input` is a string of value `"input"` (or similar), and you can't use `val()` on a collection - only singly objects.