# input placeholder transition won't remove text instantly when typing starts

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a transition on my text for a color change, so that when I click the input box, the color changes over .5 seconds. The problem is, as soon as I start typing, the same transition overlaps my text, so the placeholder text (in this case: name:) ALSO stays for .5 seconds, so 2 lines of texts are on top of each other for 5. seconds before the placeholder text goes away. Anybody know the issue? 1 of my inputs looks like this

```
<div class="form-group inner-addon left-addon">
     <label for="name"></label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control custom komigang name" id="name" placeholder="Dit navn" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" />
                        </div>

and my css for this looks like this 

.komigang::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #747c83;
    transition: .5s;
}
.komigang:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #b7b7b7;
    transition: .5s;
}
```

I figured I might be able to use a solution from this case: [Remove input placeholder using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097930/remove-input-placeholder-using-jquery) though I am looking for a more specific solution. Thanks guys

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L9vcwLf6/ - here's a quick jsfiddle where you can see an example of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to only make the transition apply to the color property - use this for your transition: `transition: .5s color;`. Also, you only need the first transition - you can remove the second one.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j440h8LL/)**

Comment: So simple, yet didn't come to my mind at all! Thanks a lot buddy, this solved it just fine!